# React Model sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am using [react-model](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-model) npm package

here is the link of my [codepen](https://codepen.io/mkhq/pen/qGgjXv)
if you check there is button close modal I want to make that button sticky

```
<button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
```

Button should not scroll with text
[image]

Comment: is it ok that button will come over the text? you can try `position: fixed`  for the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `position: sticky`.

I've wrapped the button with a div with className `sticky`, pay attention that position sticky must have `top` value.

Checkout this codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNMLpZ